# Dynamic PDF - Links not working on iPad

Tags: pdf, browser, acrobat

Can anyone shine any light on why an interactive PDF's buttons would not display on a iPad?

The following link - http://www.liquidclients.co.uk/ricky/test2.pdf  works fine on desktop - but doesnt load buttons on an iPad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in PDF rendering API in iOS renders only the page content. Annotations are not rendered. Interactive buttons are widget annotations so they are not displayed.
This is by design.

Answer (score 0):

You might try out PDFExpert by Readdle, which is said to be the leading PDF viewer for iDevices at the moment.